# javascript new window cancel original href and target

Tags: javascript

My anchor tag, opens in a new blank window if JavaScript disabled

```
<a target="_blank" onclick="newWindow(this)" href="http://www.google.co.uk">Google</a>
```

Here's my external javascript which opens the new window then cancels the original href and target from firing.

```
function newWindow(element) {

var newWin = window.open(element.href, windowName, "top=0, left=0, height=800,width=700,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no"); 


return [element.href='Javascript: void()', element.target='_self'];
}
```

This works ok for 1 click, my problem is that if the user clicks the link again then the href looks like

```
<a href="Javascript: void();">
```

so the link wont work!

What am i doing wrong?

How do I code it so once the popup window opens, the original href and target are cancelled? 
And the link can be clicked more than once?

thanks

Comment: Just make it ````<a target="_blank" onclick="newWindow(this); return false;" href="http://www.google.co.uk">Google</a>```` and no need in ````return [element.href='Javascript: void()', element.target='_self'];```` in function.

Comment: thanks @nord_ua - moving return false onto the anchor stops the href and target from firing, strange how it doesn't work in the external file.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work in the external file"?

Comment: if I return false in my external javascript and at the end of the newWindow() function then target="_blank" still fires... see response below from kraftner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is perfectly working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/tceAX/

```
<a target="_blank" onclick="newWindow(this); return false;" href="http://www.google.co.uk">Google</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function newWindow(element) {
  var newWin = window.open(element.href, 'window-name', "top=0, left=0, height=800,width=700,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the link target onClick so just replace

```
return [element.href='Javascript: void()', element.target='_self'];
```

with

```
return false
```

Comment: tried this, the new browser tab still open (target="_blank" still fires).

Answer (score 0):

In your return statement you are setting the element.href property.

```
element.href='Javascript: void()'
```

So for the first click it will work, because the element contains the original value.  But the second time you click, you already have replaced the href value.

Comment: I know this, what i'm asking is how do it so that wont happen!

Comment: You can try to return false from within the onClick attribute of the tag.  onclick="newWindow(this); return false;".